# Como calcular a velocidade média (Km/h)?

Tags: android

Preciso calcular a velocidade média (Km/h) e mostrar essa informação na Activity em "tempo real", igual é mostrado nos Apps de GPS.

Como fazer tal cálculo e codificar isso no Android?

Comment: (Distancia Inicial - Distância atual)/(tempo inicial - tempo final)?

Comment: Show, porém como expor isso pelo Android? Preciso utilizar coordenadas GPS?

Comment: Provavelmente sim.

Comment: @Beterraba e OP: não é simples. Se a terra fosse plana seria exatamente como o Beterraba indicou. Infelizmente a terra é um esferóide, então você tem que usar cálculo geodésico. Eu espero sinceramente que a API de localização do Android já tenha esse cálculo pronto.

Comment: É o que pensei também... rs, creio que não seja um calculo simples, porém também espero que o Android me retorne algo "pronto".

Comment: O método [Location.distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) já ajuda? Ele retorna a distância em metros entre duas posições considerando a Terra um _elipsóide WGS84_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()

Obter a velocidade, se estiver disponível, em metros/segundo em relação ao solo.
Se este local não tem uma velocidade de 0.0 é retornado.

se você precisa convertê-lo em km/h:

```
int speed=(int) ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser realmente calcular a velocidade por conta própria, vá estudar geometria geodésica. É mais um problema de matemática do que de programação. Ou você pode assumir que, para pequenas distâncias, a terra é plana. Lembre-se de que se fizer isso, quanto maior a distância percorrida, maior será o erro que você vai inserir no cálculo.

Existe uma alternativa <strike>sem trabalho de corno</strike> melhor: utilize o método [`getSpeed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) da classe Location ;)